# formula to calculate sga_target

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle12c

I'm trying to create a way to auto-config a pfile based on the amount of memory a server has so I was wondering if there was a formula that is used to get the ideal amount of memory to allocate to SGA_TARGET. I know I can get the ideal value by using

```
select * from v$sga_target_advice order by sga_size;
```

and like seen below there is a formula to get the PGA_AGGREGATE_TARGET

> PGA_AGGREGATE_TARGET = (Total_Ram* 0.8) * 0.5 * 1024

But is there something similar for the SGA_TARGET?

Comment: What version of Oracle?  In recent versions, you'd generally use MEMORY_TARGET rather than setting separate SGA & PGA sizes unless you have some reason to want to control them separately (which seems unlikely if you're trying to define them solely based on the amount of physical memory available).  The PGA calculation you posted would set the PGA_AGGREGATE_TARGET to 409.6 * Memory which seems really unlikely.

Comment: @JustinCave Unfortunately Oracle seems to have changed their minds and 12.2 doesn't allow automatic memory management if the server has more than 4GB of memory.